# Touch scroll within an open dialog only. Don't move the whole body

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, scroll

I have a mobile web map application within an overflow: hidden body. There is a map legend which is partially hidden on the right side of the body and a menu which is partially hidden on the bottom of the body.

The idea is to click on the partially visible part of the control and have the control slide into view.

The bottom menu is higher than the body and should therefore be scrollable in the y direction.

The problem is that I can either prevent scrolling by preventing the default on the touchmove event handler or that I enable the scrolling which means that clicking on the menu allows to move the whole body of the application all over the shop.

The application can be accessed here https://geolytix.net/mobilemap

I use Google Chrome dev tools responsive view to test the touch scroll behaviour.

I disable the scrolling on the legend item but I cannot disable the scrolling on the large menu slider on the bottom.

What I am trying to prevent is that the user just pushes the menu off the screen like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to add to your css

`html, body {position: fixed;}`

to prevent the possibility of scrolling.

Now, to make your Menu scrollable you add to your css the following lines

```
#sliderPanel {height: 100%;overflow-y: scroll;}
```

You can now scroll the Menu on the y-Axis.

Comment: position: fixed on html and body (or on the body alone) prevent the body being moved around. but i cannot scroll the menu at all. i set the overflow-y to scroll on the #sliderPanel. i have updated the live version.

Comment: You forgot to set the height:100%; on the #sliderPanel.
And it would be better, if you moved the position:fixed; inside of your materials.css

Comment: Works perfect now. Thanks a lot. I changed the live app and also remove the touch move event override which isn't required with this solution.